# Black Screen after fresh install

Tags: display

I just installed elementary and every-time that I start my computer I have a black screen after the BIOS. It's as if there is another monitor plugged in and it showing it on that one (I only have 2). I have an AMD graphics card and it is detected by the OS. My only fix so far is unplugging and replugging my video cords. Any thoughts?